# Changes in datatable saved but not applied when importing row

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable

I have a global dataset containing one datatable at the index 0. When altering values inside the table like this:

```
deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("a") = a
deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("b") = b
deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0).Rows(j).Item("c") = c
deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
```

The data inside the `deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0)` are saved.
Now some of the rows in `deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0)` should be exported to another table. Therefore i proceed as following:

```
Dim expression As String = "Field=" & field

        Dim foundRows() As DataRow
        Dim tempTable As New DataTable()

        foundRows = deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0).Select(expression)
        tempTable = deliveryNoteDataSet.Tables(0).Clone

        For Each row As DataRow In foundRows
            tempTable.ImportRow(row)
        Next

        GridControl4.DataSource = tempTable
```

The above code snippet imports the rows including their content as expected to `tempTable` except for the rows i altered before (`a, b, c`). So the values of `a,b,c` are found as desired in `foundRows` but are not exported to `tempTable`. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: can you see that row in the filtered rows? I think your filter exclude that reason, because of condition...

Comment: @ArsenMkrtchyan you mean in foundRows? yes. Can you explain that a little further please?